# How to properly packaged an electron applications

Tags: electron, electron-packager

what could be the best way to package an electron apps.

I have test and run my electron app and it works fine. Now I want to package my electron app but it just shows in command prompt

**packaging app for platform win32 ia32 using electron v5.0.6** and nothing else as can be shown in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

when I check electron version via this code **electron --version**
it output **v1.4.13** but during packaging it uses **electron v5.0.6**. Is this an electron version conflict or what?

here is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "pretty-bytes": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.6",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.35.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

can someone tell me what is wrong and why my **electron** app refuse to be packaged.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the code will eventually compile using electron-packager source [Electron Packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager). If users is compiling or packaging app for the first time, it can take up 30 minutes or more so the user has to be patient and it will package well. From the screenshot above, you can see that my app is already compiling just that I was impatient to see the end.

Waiting for about 30 minutes allows my system to finally package the app so am good to go now with electron. Thanks